# 3 column CSS liquid layout, with left and right edges flush with edges of parent element?

Tags: css, layout, html

How can I create a 3 column CSS layout, with the left and right edges flush with edges of parent element? I want to be able to do this within a liquid layout, so no fixed widths.

This sounds like it should be easy, but the best thing I can come up with is quite a hack.

```
<style>
.c3 { display:block; text-align:center; }
.c3 span { display: inline-block; width:20%; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; }
.c3 .left { float:left; }
.c3 .right { float:right; }
</style>
```

...

```
<span class="c3">
  <span class="left"> ... 
  </span>
  <span class="center"> ...
  </span>
  <span class="right"> ...
  </span>
</span>
```

You can see it [here](http://jsbin.com/eqavih/4/edit), this works okay (in my browser at least) but it just feels wrong. Is there a better way to do this?

Since there seems to be some confusion about what I'm trying to do, here it is in context. I run into this fairly often, where I already have a page layout and I want three columns within that layout. I want the three columns to be "fully justified," and I want things to be liquid, because even thought the page has a fixed layout, there's usually a facebook app or something also and I like to reuse as much as possible. Here's the [latest example](http://gitbuh.github.com/decl/site/index.html) of where I've run into this (bottom of the page).

I'm not worried about SEO, the content is usually in 1-2-3 order of importance. I don't really care if they're all the same length. I'd like to not use a ton of markup if possible. My main goal is to have the left and right edges flush with the parent element, and and equal amount of space between each column.

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote? I showed my research efforts, the question is clear, the objective seems fairly general and useful.

Comment: A lot of people on this site are ridiculous and have nothing better to do but down vote... especially if they don't feel like helping you, and if you award an answer to someone else.

Comment: Wonder what we can do to stop this worthless downvote business. The point is that people don't really understand how serious a downvote actually is.

Comment: Don't fall for this guy people. You will waste your time helping him and then he will change his question on you! down vote and run!

Comment: lol seriously? Look at what I'm trying to do, I'm clearly not looking for a fixed layout.

Comment: What you're trying to do is absolutely ridiculous... I've never even seen someone attempt such an odd thing. A layout with a bunch of spans?? I truly recommend reading a bit about of CSS.

Comment: You mean reading stuff like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=ie+support+for+inline+block)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the solution I gave in the question is the best answer for this. I haven't found any other suggestions since posting this that would achieve what I want.

I'll reiterate it here so the question can be closed.

```
<style>
.c3 { display:block; text-align:center; }
.c3 span { display: inline-block; width:20%; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; }
.c3 .left { float:left; }
.c3 .right { float:right; }
</style>
```

...

```
<span class="c3">
  <span class="left"> ... 
  </span>
  <span class="center"> ...
  </span>
  <span class="right"> ...
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: I make c3 have the style position: relative, then make .center have the style position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);

Answer (score 2):

I could try to write a new layout for you or fix the one you started, but I feel like I should just point you to a good source for the layout you're after:

> ### The Perfect 3 Column Liquid Layout (Percentage widths)
>
> #### No CSS hacks. SEO friendly. No Images. No JavaScript. Cross-browser & iPhone compatible.
>
> http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

I have used this resource for many years and it's rock solid, even in IE6. Make sure to click around to see all the examples, and read the article so you understand how it works.

This is an image of the basic layout structure (not the actual output):

[image]

It uses some crafty relative positioning and SEO-friendly 2-1-3 source order. Full height faux columns, fixed-width or fluid columns...

I cannot recommend this resource enough, I hope you enjoy it.

---

OK, sounds like you just want a lightweight alternative to your already-working solution.

Per our discussion in chat, I'm posting the mini-template I created:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div class="last">3</div> <!-- or use CSS3 :last selector -->
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
    width:500px; /* any width OK */
    float:left;
}

.wrapper div {
    width:30.65%; /* not perfect, but close */
    padding:1%;
    margin:0 0 0 1%;   
    float:left;
}

.wrapper div:first-child { margin:0; }

 /* make up for imperfect 1/3 width rounding */
.last { float:right;margin:0 }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bH8vY/2/

Best of luck.

Comment: I was just looking at this, but I don't think it does what I want. It looks like he's using that layout on that page. Try giving the right column a border that is flush with the parent element (as in my example), I don't see how it can be done. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, each page *is* a demo of the layout. "`How can I create a 3 column CSS layout, with the left and right edges flush with edges of parent element? I want to be able to do this within a liquid layout, so no fixed widths.`"... and you say this doesn't do what you want? Adding a border is certainly possible. If you have a specific question, feel free to ask it.

Comment: Still doesn't clarify anything for me. You can just toss any of these layouts into a fixed-width container. The layouts I linked to are a starting point, not the finished product. EDIT: OK, I see what you want, some kind of mini-template you can toss into pages? You can still use the layouts I linked to for that. I'm tellin ya, even with all this CSS3 wizardry of late, there is no solution for these simple things like layouts. I daresay, you might just use a table or fixed height divs.

Comment: can you make this so the red outlines are at the edges of the screen? I can't. http://jsbin.com/ivudor/edit#html,live

Comment: well, do you see anything wrong with the approach i'm using? It doesn't require a lot of markup and it gets the effect I want. Is this going to break in some way I'm not thinking of? I just don't like that  it's not semantically clean, but this alternative seems even less so. +1 for helping me out btw.

Comment: Well I don't see how you'd have *all* the borders on the edge of the screen, that makes no sense. Do you mean like this? http://jsbin.com/ivudor/4/edit Also, note that `outline` and `border` are different things entirely.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6457/discussion-between-madmartigan-and-ggg)

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want/help you; I've made a layout that uses `css` to emulate dynamic `table` behaviour [using `div`s]. It works in Chrome, Firefox and IE>7.

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/qJ48W/show/light/), have a go at resizing the window. That `middle` bit is what you want, I think.

Have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJ48W/) with it. Uncomment the `border` css line to see whats going on.

**Code:**

```html
<div class="view" style="height:100%; width:100%">
    <div class="north">
        n
    </div>

    <div class="middle">
        <div class="west">
            w
        </div>

        <div class="centre">
            c
        </div>

        <div class="east">
            e
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="south">
        s
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
html, body {
    height : 100%;
    margin : 0;
}

.view,
.view > .middle {
    display : table;
}

.view > .north,
.view > .south {
    height : 1px;
    display : table-row;
}
.view > .north { vertical-align : top; }
.view > .south { vertical-align : bottom; }

.view > .middle > div {
    display : table-cell;
}
.view > .west,
.view > .east {
    width : 1px;
}

/*div { border : 1px solid black; }*/
```

Simple markup, no JS, and dynamic layout.