# Composed HTML layout with space filling elements

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to get a layout in HTML/CSS done. The goal is about this:
[image: layout]

Some elements in this layout have a non-fixed size. The area on the left has fixed width, the footer has fixed (content matching) height. The list on the left shall be extending it's height, the text in the footer it's width and the canvas both dimensions so the entire browser page is filled, but without causing any scrollbars to appear. Oh, and B is for button, but that's not really of importance I guess.

I have seen some examples ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535186/css-layout-that-fills-available-space)) and references ([this](http://cssdesignpatterns.com/)) and tried to learn from them, but I can't get it the way I want. One of the closer attempts I have made is this one:

```
<html><body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<div style="position: absolute; background: #afa; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0; right: 0px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; background: #afa; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0; width: 240px;">
        <input style="width: 240px" id="selectedPosition"></input>
        <select style="position: relative; width: 240px; height: 100%;" id="points" multiple="multiple"></select>
        <div style="position: relative; background: #afa; left: 0; width: 240px;">
            <input style="width: 80px" type="button" value="Add"></input><!--
            --><input style="width: 80px" type="button" value="Up"></input><!--
            --><input style="width: 80px" type="button" value="Down"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div><input style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%"></input></div>
        <div><input style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 0px;" type="button" value="Button 4"></input></div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; background: #aaf; height: 100%; left: 240px;top: 0px;right: 0px; overflow: auto;"></div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Problem here is the lower elements ant the button in the bottom right are covered by size extending elements. I probably could fix this with fixed dimensions or margins, but I'd like to have it done in a "proper" way.

Another approach was to use a 4x5 table with spanning rows and columns, but I got confused even more and quickly let that drop.

I'm fairly new to layouting in HTML/CSS, so any source "for dummies" in this matter helping me getting the job done in spite of an actual solution is appreciated also.

## Update

After looking at the links and at Fico's answer. However, the closest attempt is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/TXsyT/1/). Problem is that both the list and the bottom text overlap the respective button(s) when width/height is set to 100% (in the jsfiddle example I used lower numbers for demonstration purposes). As a side note, the list in the example given does not extend vertically at all. When using my local file, then it does.

All examples I have seen with a fixed footer and height filling columns use some fixed size height for the footer which is then negatively applied as margin, but my footer should just wrap it's content. Isn't there any way to set up a rule "extend until you reach the next element"?

Comment: you can read the links: 
    http://www.brunildo.org/test/ [recommended]
    http://zomigi.com/blog/essential-resources-for-creating-liquid-and-elastic-layouts/
    http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/
    http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/
    http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp
    http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmllayout.php
    http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/layout/ [recommended]

Comment: Do not ever use `position: absolute;` for layout, except if you're proficient in CSS (and even then...). Stick with floats and `clear: both;` for a few months. edit: +1 for using a style element for your CSS rules and then moving it to an external stylesheet via link element. Inline styles are unmanageable and will keep you from seeing what you did 1 minute ago ;)

Comment: I wonder why there is position: absolute; everywhere in the examples I find. *scratches head* Actually I'm using CSS rules, the example was just made "quick and dirty".

Comment: Because position absolute makes sense for a layout like this. Saying one should never use it unless proficient in CSS is a little bogus IMO

Comment: I might have a solution, but I don't know. Check out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753303/3-column-css-liquid-layout-with-left-and-right-edges-flush-with-edges-of-parent/21251126#21251126) for another question, and if its helpful let me know and I'll re-write it so it works for what you want and submit it as an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Start by using markup for content and css for styling. 
You will work cleaner and with less trouble.
It's not a good practice to include so many  tags instead of using an external CSS  (or eventually embedded in the HEAD of the document)

It doesn't seem to me, you are in the need of so much absolute positioning here.

Identify your big areas in your design (as the figure below)
[image]

First impression is that you got an **aside** column at the left width some elements in Normal document flow and in its bottom three buttons  floating in a div

The canvas could be floating left or right of this **aside**
Both , the aside and the canvas , contained in a *mainContainer* div.

The text and button at the bottom could be integrated in a **footer** with the button floating right or left at your will

The flexible solution is simple to instrument. Use some min with properties for your canvas and probably some fixed widths for the aside.

Comment: *Sugestion:Read some stuff about Layout. Code everything again and eventually come back with any puntual problem you may find.*

Comment: Thanks, did just that. Can't figure out how to extend the list/the bottom text to only fill the free space, not more, without specifying an exact height for the footer.